# Why clicking a button fires a focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does clicking a button also fire a `focus` event?

If I have this

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
   console.log('This was a ' + e.type); 
});
$('button').on('focus', function(e){
   console.log('This was a ' + e.type); 
});
```

and HTML

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

When I click in the button , both events fire... why?

http://jsfiddle.net/PACXn/

Comment: Focus on a button occurs when that button is active. When you click on it .. you also make it active. Maybe you are looking for `mouseenter` event?

Comment: just click and wait you will know what is focus and what is a click

Comment: Clicking an object also implies you changed your focus to it. It is only natural that this event would trigger.

Comment: How do you expect to click the button without first focusing on it by mouse, keyboard, or any other means?

Comment: @bansi well, why does that behaviour not exist in a `div` element also? http://jsfiddle.net/PACXn/3/

Comment: You can do the same thing with `div`s if you assign a `tabindex` value: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvermie/PACXn/5/

Comment: This is because buttons are designed to by default to gain focus where the div element is not supposed to get focus. Even though you can add `tabindex` to non-focusable elements, i don't know of any method to remove the focus attribute from the focusable elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `<button>` always fires a focus event (when you click it). As you can read at http://api.jquery.com/focus/

> "The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`)."

Answer (score 1):

Focus on a button occurs when that button is active. When you click on it you also make it active.

You can use `mouseenter` event to simulate a human-focus like event:

```
$('button').on('mouseenter', function(e){
   console.log('This was a ' + e.type); 
});
```